# vb.net datagridview is populated only in the first row

Tags: vb.net, parsing, datagridview, html-parsing

I'm doing the parsing  from a webpage to a datagridview, but it is populated only in the first row.
Someone can give me an hand?
Thanks
Code

```
  Dim Data(10) As String
    Dim Index As Integer = 0
    Dim Output As Boolean = False

    For Each ELement As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If UCase(ELement.TagName.ToString).Contains("TD") And Output = True Then
            Data(Index) = ELement.InnerText
            Index += 1
        ElseIf UCase(ELement.TagName.ToString).Contains("TR") And Output = True Then
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

                row.Cells.Item("data").Value = Data(0)
                row.Cells.Item("data1").Value = Data(1) 
                row.Cells.Item("data2").Value = Data(2) 
                Index = 0
            Next
        End If


        Output = True

    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified a bit your code: basically I added a `rowcounter` variable to keep track of the row you're parsing.
Then I create the new row, add it to the `GridView` and fill the cells with values:

```
Dim Data(10) As String
Dim Index As Integer = 0
Dim Output As Boolean = False
Dim rowcounter As Integer = 0

For Each ELement As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
    If UCase(ELement.TagName.ToString).Contains("TD") And Output Then
        Data(Index) = ELement.InnerText
        Index += 1
    ElseIf UCase(ELement.TagName.ToString).Contains("TR") And Output Then
        If Data(0) IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim row As New DataGridViewRow
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)

            DataGridView1(0, rowcounter).Value = Data(0)
            DataGridView1(1, rowcounter).Value = Data(1)
            DataGridView1(2, rowcounter).Value = Data(2)

            rowcounter += 1

            Index = 0
        End If
    End If
    Output = True
Next
```

I also added a test on `Data(0)` to prevent adding a row when no data is available